What percentage of people in each nation have ever been incarcerated or are currently incarcerated?
Statistics of the number of people currently incarcerated (in prison, jail, brigs, confinement, detention, etc.) per nation are readily available for many nations.  This is commonly referred to as a nation's current incarceration rate.
Statistics of the total number of people who are currently within the borders a nation and have ever been incarcerated by that nation or are currently incarcerated by that nation seem to be more challenging to obtain.
Per nation, what are those rates?
Current numerical data as well as graphs showing historical trends are appreciated.

For total incarceration rate, I presume you're not intending to count people who are part of prisoner recidivism, or prisoner re-entry? That may be more difficult to separate from the incarceration rate at a given time.

As asked, this might include people in pre-trial detention, and exclude people under probation supervision if they were never locked up. A difficult statistic.

@o.m. Although I would prefer to include all forms of incarceration (including pre-trial detention), as long as the data correctly indicates whether or not it includes those values, it will have to suffice.  I prefer incomplete data with accurate footnotes over "no data" (however, if a nation holds 50% of its population in pre-trial detention, then it would need to be a big footnote).

Would someone spending a night in the drunk tank count?  Thrown in jail after a bar fight but released the next day?  Where's the cutoff?

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Those are good questions.  I was thinking about them too.  I was considering adding something like "a minimum of 24 hours", but I thought it might make it more difficult to answer, as the few statistics I've been finding don't specify that kind of detail.  Do you have any suggestions?

While it seems interesting at first glance - what proportion of people have experienced prison, I wonder what one would really learn from that, because this this a textbook example of a lagging indicator.  Take Franco's Spain in 1975 (or S. Korea/Taiwan in 80s).  Assume - I don't know - they had lots of political prisoners.  Assume that once the regime flips, the jails are emptied of non-criminals and you have a low rate of incarceration.  Your requested indicator will still show them to be high incarceration countries for decades.

The information sought does not exist for most countries.
In a minority of countries, estimates of this percentage are available (e.g. the United States) with some margin of error (because most national incarceration record keeping systems aren't designed to collect this information directly, so one has to estimate it). But a broad comparison for most nations isn't possible from existing studies.
It could be constructed from point in time incarceration rates, average incarceration duration, recidivism rates, and population size statistics, but it is a non-trivial exercise. Many efforts to estimate this number simply survey people and ask them, without confirming the accuracy of the responses, but such surveys aren't so standard that they have been done in most countries.
In the United States:

An estimated 5.1% of all persons in the United States will be confined
in a State or Federal prison during their lifetime, if incarceration
rates recorded in 1991 remain unchanged in the future.  The lifetime
chances of a person going to prison are higher for men (9.0%) than for
women (1.1%) and higher for blacks (16.2%) and Hispanics (9.4%) than
for whites (2.5%).  At current levels of incarceration a black male in
the United States today has greater than a 1 in 4 chance of going to
prison during his lifetime, while a Hispanic male has a 1 in 6 chance
and a white male has a 1 in 23 chance of serving time. The lifetime
likelihood of incarceration, the focus of this study, represents the
percentage of all U.S. residents expected to be incarcerated in a
prison at some time in life.   Such a measure is hypothetical based
on the assumption that recent rates of incarceration (and death rates)
will not change in the future.  Unlike a standard incarceration rate,
which expresses the prevalence of incarceration on a single day, the
lifetime likelihood measure summarizes the chances of a person being
incarcerated at some time over an entire lifetime.

